# Moving Info Between View Controllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, transition

I'm new to iOS, and am trying to figure something out that is probably basic. I have two UIViews, with four buttons on each page, and four labels underneath each button. Basically, if I push button 1 on view controller 1, I would like all of the labels on view controller two to simply read "2". Here is an image for a better visual:

[image]

I setup outlets for each UIButton on view controller 1, and outlets for each label on view controller 2.

```
- (IBAction)button1Pressed:(id)sender {

    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController2"];
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];

    ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc]init];
    vc2.label1.text = @"1";
    vc2.label2.text = @"1";
    vc2.label3.text = @"1";
    vc2.label4.text = @"1";

}
```

It transitions just fine. But, I'm having trouble with trying to change the label's text during the transition. I'm getting three errors: "Unknown receiver: ViewController2" , "Unknown type name:  ViewController2" , and "Property `label1` not found on object of type ViewController *". So, it appears that I'm having trouble setting up changing the text. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
vc2.label1.text = @"1";
vc2.label2.text = @"1";
vc2.label3.text = @"1";
vc2.label4.text = @"1";
```

with

```
vc.label1.text = @"1";
vc.label2.text = @"1";
vc.label3.text = @"1";
vc.label4.text = @"1";
```

And remove

```
ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc]init];
```

Comment: Thank you. I did that, and I'm getting the error "Property label1 not found on object of type UIViewController".

Comment: Oh, I see.  You will want to create a new class that inherits from UIViewController and has public properties of the 4 labels.  Then create vc as that type of view controller, not just a standard one.

Comment: Thank you. That went way over my head, but I will research it

Comment: I have found the AppCoda tutorials to be very good at explaining stuff like that.  I do believe they have a tutorial on passing data with segues

Answer (score 1):

The view controller you are presenting, the one that is about to appear, is `vc`. That is where you want to set the labels.

The thing referred to in the last five lines of your code, `vc2`, is nothing: it's just something you bring into existence for five lines and then it vanishes in a puff of smoke, to no purpose. It's hard even to imagine what you could possibly think those lines of code are for.